# Mongo CursorTimeout Exception

Tags: mongodb

I am having this mongo cursor timeout exception. Actually, I am making a feed aggregator from social sites like twitter and facebook. I am running a cron to fetch the tweets every two minutes and persisting those tweets to my local db. I have another script that is parsing the feeds and extracting required information and persisting them to another database. The problem is the parser is running continuously and parsing the feeds. However, I am having this cursor time out exception. I am trying to retrieve just 50 tweets at a time from the local db for parsing. Still it is throwing cursor exception
I have also indexed the database properly. FYI my server has harddisk of 8GB and ram of 700 MB. I think this configuration should have been enough for the start. Currently I have just 60000 tweets stored in my database out of which 20000 need to be parsed. But still it is throwing cursor timeout exception continuously.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What language is the code in? In the Ruby and Java drivers you can disable cursor timeout - I am sure you can in others too. Read up the driver documentation.

Comment: please answer this question and others you have for the users whom have provided you with answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you using a PHP driver, you can turn off the timeout for all queries by

`MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;` (-1 is no timeout)

And I think other drivers may have the same options for query. (read the manual)

Comment: is it really safe to totally remove the timeout?

Comment: I'm not sure about 'totally' safe, but I have been used this option in slave mongod over 6 months and there was no severe problems. ( My slowest query is about 30min )