# MongoDB too many records?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a PHP app that interacts with MongoDB. Until recently, the app was working fine but a few days back I found that the app is starting to respond REALLY slow. One of the collections has shot up to 500K+ records. So the MongCursor for any query on that collection keeps timing out.

I don't think 500K records is WAY too much. Other pages using mongodb are beginning to slow down as well, but not as much as the one which uses the collection with 500k records. Static pages which don't interact with MongoDB are still fast to respond.

I am not sure what could be the issue here. I have indexed the collections, so that does not seem to be a problem. Another point to note is that the RAM spec on the server is 512 MB and when PHP executes Mongo, top command show 15000k memory free.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Helpful to include a sample query with [.explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarize followup from the chat room, the issue is actually related to a find() query which is doing a scan of all ~500k documents to find 15:

```
db.tweet_data.find({ 
    $or: 
    [ 
        { in_reply_to_screen_name: /^kunalnayyar$/i, handle: /^kaleycuoco$/i, id: { $gt: 0 } }, 
        { in_reply_to_screen_name: /^kaleycuoco$/i, handle: /^kunalnayyar$/i, id: { $gt: 0 } } 
    ], 
    in_reply_to_status_id_str: { $ne: null }
} ).explain() 
{ 
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_1", 
    "nscanned" : 523248, 
    "nscannedObjects" : 523248, 
    "n" : 15, 
    "millis" : 23682, 
    "nYields" : 0, 
    "nChunkSkips" : 0, 
    "isMultiKey" : false, 
    "indexOnly" : false, 
    "indexBounds" : { 
        "id" : [ 
            [ 
                0, 
                1.7976931348623157e+308 
            ] 
        ] 
    } 
}
```

This query is using [case-insensitive regular expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) which won't make efficient use of an index (though there wasn't actually one defined, in this case).

Suggested approach:

- create lowercase `handle_lc` and `inreply_lc` fields for search purposes
- add a [compound index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeys) on those:

  `db.tweet.ensureIndex({handle_lc:1, inreply_lc:1})`
- the order of the compound index allows efficient find of all tweets either by `handle` or by (`handle,in_reply_to`)
- search by exact match instead of regex:

`db.tweet_data.find({ 
         $or: 
         [ 
            { in_reply_to_screen_name:'kunalnayyar', handle:'kaleycuoco', id: { $gt: 0 } }, 
            { in_reply_to_screen_name:'kaleycuoco', handle:'kunalnayyar', id: { $gt: 0 } } 
        ], 
     })`

Comment: Why can't I use single indexes here? Also, I realized another issue - there is a descending sort on the field "id". So I guess I'll have to modify my indexes, any suggestions?

Comment: @AyushChaudhary: In the general case MongoDB only uses [one index per query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Oneindexperquery.). If you expect a lot of tweets and are searching by both handle + replyto, a compound index would make sense so the [index matches your queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Oneindexperquery.).  If you are always sorting by _id you could add this into the compound index as well.

Comment: Read the [Indexing Strategies](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ) page on the MongoDB wiki for more tips. If you compare the output of different approaches using [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) you should get more insight on how to optimize the queries/indexes. You probably want to use [limit()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Blimit%28%29%7D%7D) along with your [sort()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D) to avoid fetching too many documents.

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations! The most probable oe being (db.tweet_data.ensureIndex({in_reply_to_screen_name:1, handle:1, id:-1}, {background:true}). Even this fails on "sort", works find without sort. Could it be the name of the field "id" ?

Comment: @AyushChaudhary: as suggested on your related [SO follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703716/mongodb-sort-is-extremely-slow-even-on-indexed-fields), you need to work with [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) to understand how an index is being used (or not) for your query.  Start with the simplest query and then add additional criteria to see how the explain changes, in particular for the number of objects that need to be scanned to find your result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 500K+ should be okay..To my knowledge, there's no real 'limit' on the number of docs in a collection..probably, it is the number of unique combinations of _id field MongoDB can generate..But that would be much larger than 500K..In your case, what I suspect is, maybe your query is not very selective. So when there were fewer documents in the collection, you didn't notice the issue. But with the increase, it suddenly seems to be getting sluggish..like, how many documents is the MongoCursor returning?

Comment: It actually varies. In some cases, it can give me 100, in some 0, in some 500.

Comment: So have you checked how the performance varies with varying number of documents returned?

Comment: There isn't much variation with the number of records. The cursor keeps timing out with 30s most of the times

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015822/mongo-cursortimeout-exception

Comment: Hmm, that is one solution. But I want to find out what could be making things slow here?

Comment: cursor mongo timed out {30000ms}
Do you suspect it could be the RAM slowing things down?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14567/discussion-between-aafreen-sheikh-and-ayush-chaudhary)