# MongoDB sort is extremely slow even on indexed fields

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

So I had this issue today where my MongoDB queries where extremely slow and timing out. I posted this question - [MongoDB too many records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701103/mongodb-too-many-records) and his suggestion was right wherein I had to ensureIndex and remove case-insensitivity. I tried it in Mongo shell, it worked perfectly.

However, when I ran it via PHP, it was still the same :(
I then realized the query had a sort on "id" (not _id) field and when I removed that, things were blazing fast. But with the sort, it was REALLY slow. I already had an index on the id field. 
This is the query btw :

```
db.tweet_data.find({ 
...     $or: 
...         [ 
...             { in_reply_to_screen_name: /^kunalnayyar$/, handle: /^kaleycuoco$/, id: { $gt: 0 } }, 
...             { in_reply_to_screen_name: /^kaleycuoco$/, handle: /^kunalnayyar$/, id: { $gt: 0 } } 
...         ], 
...     in_reply_to_status_id_str: { $ne: null } 
...     
...     } ).sort({id:-1})explain()
```

So my indexes are : (not composite) `{ {id:-1} , {handle:1}, {in_reply_to_screen_name:1} }`
After some reading I realized it should have been a composite index and I tried two variations to no success : 
1. `{handle:1, in_reply_to_screen_name:1, id:-1}`
2. `{id:-1,handle:1, in_reply_to_screen_name:1}`

I am not sure where I am going wrong, but I am pretty sure the issue is indexing here. I am just too buzzed and can't understand the order and the fields to index

Comment: Depends on the order of fields in your document..Try {in_reply_to_screen_name:1, handle:1} or {in_reply_to_screen_name:1, handle:1, id:-1}

Comment: Only {in_reply_to_screen_name:1, handle:1} won't work because there is a sort on {id:-1} I have tried both variations of handle, in_reply, id but nothing has worked.

Comment: {in_reply_to_screen_name:1, handle:1, id:-1} should do..And this is different from the two that you mention you have tried..When I said, "depends on the order of fields in the document", I meant the "search document".

Comment: @Ayush: do you need the `id: { $gt: 0 }` in the query, or has that been removed?  If that is actually a default [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) you shouldn't need to assert it is greater than 0.  Similarly, you may want to include `in_reply_to_status_id_str` in the `$or` queries/index rather than separately.  I would try [explaining](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) the individual queries first before combining in an `$or`.

Comment: Do the indexes need to match "ALL" the fields being queried and exactly?

Comment: Also, have a look at the `nScanned` numbers in the explain() versus the `n`.

Comment: Well, this getting weirder. These are my indexes `"key" : {
   "in_reply_to_screen_name" : 1,
   "handle" : 1,
   "created_at" : -1
  }`
and I ran a query `$or: 
... ...         [ 
... ...             { in_reply_to_screen_name: /^kunalnayyar$/, handle: /^kaleycuoco$/}, 
... ...             { in_reply_to_screen_name: /^kaleycuoco$/, handle: /^kunalnayyar$/} 
... ...         ]
... ...     
... ...     } ).sort({created_at:-1}).explain()
` It still didn't use indexes!

Comment: @AyushChaudhary: it depends on your common queries, so really you need to use [explain](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) to understand how indexes are used and [profiling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler) to find slow queries. See also the [Indexing Advice/Strategies](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-IndexingStrategies).

Comment: @AyushChaudhary: why are you still using regex instead of exact match?    Have you also tried explain() on a single query in the `$or`?  You should edit with the exact query rather than "...".   Also, how selective is the screenname/handle in your test data (i.e. of the 500k tweets, are these still a small number of matching documents?

Comment: Yes, without the OR it apparently used the index.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `explain` against your query, it will help you figure out what's going on.

It's likely that Mongo isn't using an index for both filtering and sorting. When you use an `$or`, it can use multiple indexes to match the options. But when you add a `sort` it may make it not use indexes available for filtering.

When you want to sort on a query, you need to make sure the sorted field is in the index you want to hit (last, or it can't use it to sort).

You may be able to speed it up by passing an index hint, too. I don't know how many docs your query matches, but if it's a small number and you make sure the initial conditions are hitting an index, the sort on `_id` can be done quickly.